# Celery default configuration file

Tags: python, celery

I am installing Celery through Puppet and I would like to also have a default configuration file to provide to Celery. The default name is `celeryconfig.py`, but I don't know where to copy it.

I am NOT using Celery with Django.

What is the location where I should copy `celeryconfig.py` in order for Celery to read it everytime it runs?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer put configs to project root folder:

1. One easy style to load config.
2. One easy style to find and edit config.

However you should load configs manually with one of next methods: `config_from_object`, `config_from_envvar` or `config_from_cmdline`.

Comment: I know about those. But there is the possibility of having multiple projects and I want them to share base configuration (such as broker or backend etc), thus placing (if case) a config file in a project if I want to have other configuration.

Comment: 1. The easiest way is put config for each project, it easy update project and configs with `puppet`, `fabric`, `chef`, `saltstack`. 2. You also can put confgis to one specific file on file system, like `/etc/` for linux, but probably `/etc/` better for system packages not for own projects. 3. You can use `envvar` instead file. 4. You can use package with configs, just install egg from file system or if you have own pypi mirror or private csv project (also can look at git submodules and etc.) for this. 5. You can up specific server which will return configs by request.